# scala import library wildcard

Tags: scala, import, wildcard

I am new to scala. Please be gentle.

The import below imports everything (every class, trait and object) under ml.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml._
```

but NOT ParamMap, which is under

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.param._
```

In other words, for the code below, if I do:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.param._
import org.apache.spark.ml._

class Kmeans extends Transformer {
 def copy(extra: ParamMap): Unit = {
   defaultCopy(extra)
}}
```

Then I have no import errors, but if I comment `import org.apache.spark.ml.param._`:

```
//import org.apache.spark.ml.param._
import org.apache.spark.ml._

class Kmeans extends Transformer {
 def copy(extra: ParamMap): Unit = {
   defaultCopy(extra)
}}
```

It gives an import error on ParamMap.

> Question

why isn't this `import org.apache.spark.ml.param.ParamMap` included `import org.apache.spark.ml.param._`

Comment: note that you can do `import org.apache.spark.ml._, param._`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala imports are not recursive - `import org.apache.spark.ml._` means import all classes and fields *directly* under `ml` package but not the ones under its sub-packages.

Since `ParamMap` is under one of `ml`'s sub-packages (`ml.param`), you'll have to import that package or `ParamMap` class directly.

Comment: or just write `def copy(extra: param.ParamMap)`